# не получается разместить результат file_get_contents в теле HTTP запроса в PHP

Tags: php, http, soap, binary

Есть содержимое файла которое в виде бинарных даных надо отправить в теле HTTP запроса (мегатезнология МТОМ+ХОР если это важно). Испольовал разные методы для получения содержимого доступные в PHP, но результат примерно один и тот же - кракозябры которые отваливаются по первому же символу переноса строки. Вот начало файла (PHP шторм конвертнул все непонятное в ЮНИКОД, где-то по \u0000  отрезается содержимое, в оригинале выглядит конечно по-другому)

```
"PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0002\u0000\b\u0000pWvK\u0014����\u0002\u0000\u00007\u0007\u0000\u0000-\u0000\u0000\u0000piev_fe2a1af4-cf5a-11e7-a410-8b2
```

То каким оно кладется в тело запроса

```
--TITO-d13729e676bbe2d51220340d80c6a44b
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=piev_fe2a1af4-cf5a-11e7-a410-8b2cf6344555.zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <piev_fe2a1af4-cf5a-11e7-a410-8b2cf6344555.zip>
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="piev_fe2a1af4-cf5a-11e7-a410-8b2cf6344555.zip"; filename="piev_fe2a1af4-cf5a-11e7-a410-8b2cf6344555.zip"
PK
```

Что надо с ним сделать чтобы оно в нужном виде легло в тело запроса?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось что я сам себе дурак. Оно его нормально помещает в тело запроса, Размещу тут код создания МТОМ запроса на пыхе с помощью курла.
Функция осздания тела запроса:

```
function createRequestBodyFrom($xml, &$boundary){
    $boundary = 'TITO-' . md5(time());
    $eol = "\r\n";
    $content = file_get_contents('Путь_к_файлу');   

    $fileID = 'Название_файла';
    $requestBody = '--'. $boundary . $eol;
    $requestBody .= 'Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"'. $eol;
    $requestBody .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'. $eol;
    $requestBody .= 'Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org>'. $eol. $eol;
    $requestBody .= $xml. $eol;
    $requestBody .= '--'. $boundary . $eol;
    $requestBody .= 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name='. $fileID . $eol;
    $requestBody .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'. $eol;
    $requestBody .= 'Content-ID: <'.$fileID.'>' . $eol. $eol;
    $requestBody .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; name="'.$fileID.'"; filename="'.$fileID.'"' . $eol;
    $requestBody .= $content. $eol;
    return $requestBody;
}
```

Отсправка созданного запроса (У меня всегда 1 аттач, так что функция сверху заточена под добавление одного аттача. Так же считается что ХМЛ уже заранее сформирована с нужным ХОПом. Т.е. у вас уже есть все компоненты чтобы собрать из них целый запрос.

```
$requestBody = createRequestBodyFrom($request, $boundary);
$headers = array(
            'Content-type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="'.$boundary.'"',
            "SOAPAction: \"Навание_Soap_Action\"",
            "Accept: text/xml",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Pragma: no-cache",
            "Content-length: ".strlen($requestBody),
        );
$soap_do = curl_init();
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            'Адрес_сервиса' );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $requestBody);        
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '' . ":" . '');
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
```